# How to parse JSON String with Date attribute

Tags: javascript, json, yui, stringify

I am trying to find a way to parse a JSON string which contains Date object.

```
> var obj = {}
> obj.date = new Date();
Mon Mar 19 2012 15:14:22 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> obj.number = 1
1
> obj.float = 1.1
1.1
> obj.str = "hello"
"hello"
> obj
Object
date: Mon Mar 19 2012 15:14:22 GMT-0700 (PDT)
float: 1.1
number: 1
str: "hello"

> YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify(obj)
"{"date":"\"2012-03-19T22:14:22Z\"","number":1,"float":1.1,"str":"hello"}"

> parsed = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(str)
Object
date: ""2012-03-19T22:14:22Z""
float: 1.1
number: 1
str: "hello"
```

see that parsed.date is string where obj.date was previously Date object. What is the best way to parse JSON with nested objects?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

JSON cannot be used to de-serialize objects (`Date` > String <del>> `Date`</del>).
Only strings, numbers, object (literals), arrays, booleans and null can be serialiszed well.

You have to write a custom parser, which deals with the `Date` object as follows:

- Parse: Parse the timestamp using the `Date` constructor. eg `new Date(timestamp);`.

  ```
  function parse(str) {
      var obj = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(str);
      obj.date = new Date(obj);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use yui [stringToDate](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.lang.JSON.html) function stringToDate turns strings in the iso8601 UTC format into Dates :

```
var parsed = YAHOO.lang.Json.stringToDate(str);
```

parsed.date will now contain a Date object and other element will be de_serialized too.

see an example [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/json/json_freeze_thaw_log.html).